# Drag and drop images in same div javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my problem: I have two divs with the same id and class. Inside them there are photos with different ids and same class.

```
    function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    if(ev.target.getAttribute('class') == data)
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

I'm using this function to drag and drop the images to one div to another but I can drag only the first image in the div and I can't understand why.
What's wrong?

Hope that can help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHXS9.jpg

Comment: `I have two divs with the same id and class` ids have to be unique across the page.

Comment: Id's have to be unique. Try to change one id and then retry

Comment: Other problem: I want to move the images only in different div of the same row. What I have to change?